# DRF How to overide the way objects are written to DB

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a field in my model that contains a string. That string is given in plaintext when there is a create, patch or partial patch call to the API endpoint. But the value stored in the DB should be encrypted.
But if there is a list or retrieve call, then the encrypted value should be displayed.

Having the field as "write_only" is not an option as I need to retrieve the encrypted string via the API.

So the problem is that I have to take the input value and encrypt before it gets stored on the DB. But when I retrieve the objects then the value should be displayed as it is stored in the DB.

One solution I was thinking of was to use different serializers for the different methods in the Viewset and having a method field that encrypts the string. And a simple CharField to display the value in the other serializer.

Another could be to change the object model itself to have the functionality build in the model.

But maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can go with having multiple serializers, you can decrypt the value in one serializer if in case you need it in string format and in other serializer you can return encrypted values. All you have to do is encrypt the values before saving it and you can call get_serializer_class to call multiple serializer on multiple conditon